# Using jQuery to change a string of HTML: wont update the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have some JQuery that takes 2 strings of HTML. Each string contains exactly the same html except in one string the innertext contents of each element will be different, this string is called **newContent**, the other **oldContent**.

**My function:** iterates over oldContent, for each element of the class "updatable"(inside oldContent) we change its innerText to the innerText of the same element in newContent.

**My Problem:** it is not changing the contents of oldContent, after I perform the function, oldContent contains the exact same HTML (where what should happen is that elements of the class updatable should have different innerText).

Why doesn't the string oldContent change?

```
    function insertContentIntoUpdatableElements( oldContent, newContent )
{
    // Pre: oldContent & newContent must be strings of HTML returned from jquery's
    //      $("").html()

    try
    {
        alert("BEFORE: "+oldContent);
        var index       = 0;
        var oldElements = $(oldContent).find(".updatable");
        var newElements = $(newContent).find(".updatable");

        $(oldContent).find(".updatable").each( function()
        {
            var txt = $(newElements[index]).text(); alert("TEXT: "+txt); 
            alert("OLD TEXT: "+$(this).text());
            $(this).text(txt);
            index++;

            alert("NEW TEXT: "+$(this).text());  // prints out CORRECT updated/changed text
        });

        alert("AFTER: "+oldContent);   // prints out INCORRECT updated/changed text for each element of class "updatable"
        return oldContent;
    }
    catch(ex) { alert("In insertContentIntoUpdatableElements(): "+ex); return "FAILED"; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
  function insertContentIntoUpdatableElements( oldContent, newContent )
  {
    var result = $(oldContent);
    var oldElements = result.find(".updatable");
    var newElements = $(newContent).find(".updatable");

    $(oldElements).each(function(index, el)
    {
      $(oldElements[index]).text($(newElements[index]).text());
    });
    return result;
  }
```

**See a working Demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZVgh/**